# Path components of complex analytic spaces

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a [complex analytic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analytic_space). Are the path components of $X$ the same as the connected components?

Comment: I don’t  understand how does having structure  $\mathcal{O}_X$ makes any difference to the question

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Complex analytic spaces are locally homeomorphic to zero sets of finitely many holomorphic functions $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I do know what an analytic space is, just the definition though.. I did not knew having this extra structure says something about no of path components and connected components.. I am also eagerly waiting for answer to this question. +1.. why don’t you Register here in this site

Comment: Since Analytic spaces can be triangulated path components and connected components are the same.